# Verificação isset em python (detalhes)

Tags: python, json

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, no PHP tenho um código `curl` que retorna alguns `json` como podem ver no código:

```
$response = curl_exec($request);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$json = substr($response, $header_size);
$json = json_decode($json);

curl_close($request);
```

Verifica se existe o objeto **authenticated**, é aqui o meu problema no Python, como verifico isso no python?

```
if (isset($json->authenticated) && $json->authenticated === false && $json->user === true)
{
  return ['incorrect_password'];
}
```

Em python eu tenho a mesma coisa, porém preciso verificar esse `isset($json->authenticated)`

Veja:

```
post = response['session'].post(self.url['login'], data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)

jsons = json.loads(post.text)

if not jsons['authenticated'] and not jsons['user']:
  return 'incorrect_user'
```

Eu já tentei:

```
if jsons['authenticated'] and not jsons['authenticated'] and not jsons['user']:
```

Até mesmo tentei o uso de `try | exceptions`

Mas não estou entendo essa lógica.

Como fazer corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## verificando se uma chave existe em um dicionário

Os dicionários em Python usam o operador `in` para verificar se uma chave existe ou não  - então um `if` poderia ficar assim:

```
if not 'authenticated'  in jsons or not jsons['authenticated']:
```

Quand queremos saber se uma coisa *não* é contida em outra, como acima, há uma sintaxe alternativa que é recomendada - escrever o "not" junto com o "in" - 
(estou explicando separadamente, por que por que isso é uma exceção de sintaxe que compila o código de um jeito especial. Ordinariamente o `not` é um operador unário):

```
if not 'authenticated'  in jsons or not jsons['authenticated']:
```

As recomendações de estilo para escrever programas em Python indicam essa forma, em vez da primeira.

## Forma recomendada:

E por fim, a forma recomendada - quando você quer ao mesmo tempo saber se uma chave existe num dicionário e se existir, comparar o seu valor, a forma correta é usar o método `.get` dos dicionários, em vez da expressão em dois estágios como acima. O `.get` tenta achar um valor no dicionário, e, se não existe, retorna `None` (em vez de `KeyError`):

```
if jsons.get("authenticated"):
    # Código só é executado aqui se a chave `authenticated` existir
    # e o seu valor for um objeto com valor verdadeiro.
```

Só pra completar, o método `.get` aceita um segundo argumento opcional, que é o valor retornado se a chave não existir. Então você pode preverir escrever:

```
if jsons.get("authenticated", False):
```

Fica mais claro que se o valor não existir, é considerado como se ele fosse `False`.

## Só pra completar:

Além do método `.get`, os dicionários em Python também tem o método `.setdefault`. Ele aceita sempre dois argumentos e funciona como o `.get`: se a chave existe no dicionário, o valor que exist é retornado. Se a chave não existe, o segundo argumento é retornado. A diferença é que nesse caso, ele não só retorna o valor, mas *cria* o valor no dicionário também.

Ele é útil quando estamos, por exemplo, criando um dicionário em que os valores serão listas - se quisermos por exemplo, ter um dicionário com todas as posições das palavras em uma lista:

```py
dados = ["urso", "gato", "cachorro", "cachorro", "urso", "gato", "gato", "gato"]

resultados = {}
for posicao, palavra in enumerate(dados):
    resultados.setdefault(palavra, []).append(posicao)
```

Ou seja: pra cada palavra, se ela ainda não existe como chave no dicionário, uma nova lista, vazia, é criada e colocada lá. Se a palavra já existe, a lista que já está no dicionário é retornada. Em qualquer caso, o `.setdefault` devolve uma lista, e já fazemos `append` na lista pra incluir o valor desejado (no caso, a posição da palavra);

A saída disso será:

```
In [163]: resultados                                                                                                                                   
Out[163]: {'urso': [0, 4], 'gato': [1, 5, 6, 7], 'cachorro': [2, 3]}
```

Comment: Muito boa explicação, obrigado, só uma dúvida complementar, esse json,get(valor, param) só pode ser True ou False?

Comment: Não - o segundo argumento pode ser qualquer coisa. Também existe o método `.setdefault` - que se o valor não existir, ele é criado no dicionário. 

Vou complementar na resposta